# How to disable fill handle only for a specific column in Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with multiple columns, some containing cells with dropdown lists. 
 I want to disable the fill handle functionality where you can multiply cell data by dragging down the "+" sign from the corner of a cell. 
 I want to do this because my dropdowns in that specific column are populated differently by an id in that row and I want to avoid wrong data insert. 
 I've found how to do that to the whole spreadsheet but I can't find a way to apply this to a single column.

Comment: Even if you could, it will not be any good as someone can paste over that range... Alternative: You can handle that in the `Worksheet_Change` event and undo it?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I don't want to protect the cell/column. Those are dropdown cells and I want to allow to insert/change data only from the dropdown list options. Thanks.

Comment: Handle it in the `Worksheet_Change` event  like I mentioned baove

Comment: If you need a hint then see [Allow Paste Special Only](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/09/17/vba-excelallow-paste-special-only/) Obviously that link talks about "Paste Special" but then you can see how the undo stack is handled and how "Paste" and "Autofill"" is trapped.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer you can't. It is not possible to disable this for only specific cells.

And actually if you disable it in the Excel Options

```
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
```

It will be disabled for the whole Excel application.

Comment: What about combining your answer with `Worksheet_SelectionChange`? OP could check if `Target` is in a specific column and if true, then `Application.CellDragAndDrop = False`... I would post it but I thought about that looking at your answer so actually the idea is yours LoL

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I thought about that already. My thoughts: Because it affects the whole application it would be a mess to set it `True` eg. if you have multiple workbooks and worksheets you need to set it `True` if it switches. While you could probably handle that with multiple events, you could not prevent pulling down a cell into the target area (from outside the target area). Because selection is not within the target we cannot deactivate drag/drop butt still drag the cell and drop into the target (that should be protected).